# Create a multidimensional array dynamically in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-allocation

What is the good way (understand idiomatic/good practice) to dynamically create a multidimensional array in C++.

For example let say I have tree integers `w`, `h` and `d` and I want to create an array `MyEnum my_array[w][h][d]`. (Of course w, h and d are not known at compile time).

Is it best to use nested std::vector or use new or something ?

Bonus question : Is it possible to set the dimension dynamically too ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, nesting `std::vector` is not a great idea. It's usually a better plan to allocate memory which will hold the entirety of your multidimensonal array as a contiguous block, and then index into it *as if* it were multidimensional. This memory block *could* be allocated via `new`, but unless you need some precise control over how it's allocated (custom allocator), I'd recommend sticking with a single `std::vector`.

It's not difficult to create a class to manage such a resource in which the number of dimensions can be set dynamically. A good way to organize such a class is to keep track of the allocated memory, the sizes of each dimension, and the *stride pattern* for each dimension. The strides describe how many elements must be incremented over in order to reach the next element along a given dimension.

This allows efficient indexing (just pointer arithmetic), as well as *very* efficient reshaping: as long as the number of elements doesn't change, this just requires changing the shape and stride arrays.

---

**Example:**

Here's a very basic class which will store such a dynamical multidimensional array of `double`s. It stores data in row-major order, meaning that the last index varies the fastest. So for a 2D array, the first row is stored contiguously, followed by the second row, and so on.

You can reshape the array, changing the number of dimensions, if you want. A basic element access `operator[]` is shown, too. There's nothing else fancy about the class, but you can extend it to provide whatever functionality you want, e.g., iterators, mathematical operations on the data, I/O operators, etc.

```
/*! \file dynamic_array.h
 * Basic dynamic multi-dimensional array of doubles.
 */

#ifndef DYNAMIC_ARRAY_H
#define DYNAMIC_ARRAY_H

#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <functional>

class
dynamic_array
{
    public:
        dynamic_array(const std::vector<int>& shape)
            : m_nelem(std::accumulate(shape.begin(), shape.end(),
                        1, std::multiplies<int>()))
            , m_ndim(shape.size())
            , m_shape(shape)
        {
            compute_strides();
            m_data.resize(m_nelem, 0.0);
        }

        ~dynamic_array()
        {
        }

        const double& operator[](int i) const
        {
            return m_data.at(i);
        }

        double& operator[](int i)
        {
            return m_data.at(i);
        }

        const double& operator[](const std::vector<int>& indices) const
        {
            auto flat_index = std::inner_product(
                    indices.begin(), indices.end(),
                    m_strides.begin(), 0);
            return m_data.at(flat_index);
        }

        double& operator[](const std::vector<int>& indices)
        {
            auto flat_index = std::inner_product(
                    indices.begin(), indices.end(),
                    m_strides.begin(), 0);
            return m_data.at(flat_index);
        }

        void reshape(const std::vector<int>& new_shape)
        {
            auto new_nelem = std::accumulate(
                    new_shape.begin(), new_shape.end(),
                    1, std::multiplies<int>());
            if (new_nelem != m_nelem) {
                throw std::invalid_argument("dynamic_array::reshape(): "
                        "number of elements must not change.");
            }
            m_nelem = new_nelem;
            m_ndim = new_shape.size();
            m_shape = new_shape;
            compute_strides();
        }

        const std::vector<int>& shape() const
        {
            return m_shape;
        }

        const std::vector<int>& strides() const
        {
            return m_strides;
        }

        int ndim() const
        {
            return m_ndim;
        }

        int nelem() const
        {
            return m_nelem;
        }

    private:
        int m_ndim;
        int m_nelem;
        std::vector<int> m_shape;
        std::vector<int> m_strides;
        std::vector<double> m_data;

        void compute_strides()
        {
            m_strides.resize(m_ndim);
            m_strides.at(m_ndim - 1) = 1;
            std::partial_sum(m_shape.rbegin(),
                    m_shape.rend() - 1,
                    m_strides.rbegin() + 1,
                    std::multiplies<int>());
        }
};

#endif // include guard
```

Here's a basic demo of the functionality.

```
/*! \file test.cc
 * Basic test of the dynamic_array class.
 */
#include "dynamic_array.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int /* argc */, const char * /* argv */[])
{
    dynamic_array arr({2, 3});
    std::cout << "Shape: { ";
    for (auto& each : arr.shape())
        std::cout << each << " ";
    std::cout << "}" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Strides: { ";
    for (auto& each : arr.strides())
        std::cout << each << " ";
    std::cout << "}" << std::endl;

    // Reshape array, changing number of dimensions, but
    // keeping number of elements constant.
    arr.reshape({6});
    std::cout << "Shape: { ";
    for (auto& each : arr.shape())
        std::cout << each << " ";
    std::cout << "}" << std::endl;

    // Verify that the stride pattern has now also changed.
    std::cout << "Strides: { ";
    for (auto& each : arr.strides())
        std::cout << each << " ";
    std::cout << "}" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You can compile the test program with `g++ -std=c++14 -o test test.cc`, assuming the file defining the class is in the same directory as `test.cc`.

Comment: Thank you that's the kind of answer I was looking for !