# Fast element access for multi-dimensional representation of contiguous array

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, optimization, variadic-templates

I have a multi-dimensional array represented contiguously in memory. I want to keep this representation hidden and just let the user access the array elements as if it were a multi-dimensional one: e.g. `my_array[0][3][5]` or `my_array(0,3,5)` or something similar. The dimensions of the object are not determined until runtime, but the object is created with a type that specifies how many dimensions it has. This element look-up will need to be called billions of times, and so should hopefully involve minimal overhead for each call.

I have looked at similar questions but not really found a good solution. Using the `[]` operator requires the creation of `N-1` dimensional objects, which is fine for multi-dimensional structures like vectors-of-vectors because the object already exists, but for a contiguous array it seems like it would get convoluted very quickly and require some kind of slicing through the original array.

I have also looked at overloading `()`, which seems more promising, but requires specifying the number of arguments, which will vary depending upon the number of dimensions of the array. I have thought about using list initialization or vectors, but wanted to avoid instantiating objects.

I am only a little familiar with templates and figure that there should be some way with C++'s majestic template powers to specify a unique overloading of `()` for arrays with different types (e.g. different numbers of dimensions). But I have only used templates in really basic generic cases like making a function use both `float` and `double`.

I am imagining something like this:

```
template<typename TDim>
class MultiArray {
public:
  MultiArray() {} //build some things
  ~MultiArray() {} //destroy some things

  // The number of arguments would be == to TDim for the instantiated class
  float& operator() (int dim1, int dim2, ...) {
    //convert to contiguous index and return ref to element
    // I believe the conversion equation is something like:
    // dim1 + Maxdim1 * ( dim2 + MaxDim2 * ( dim3 + MaxDim3 * (...)))
  }

private:
  vector<float> internal_array;
  vector<int> MaxDimX; // Each element says how large each corresponding dim is.
};
```

So if I initialize this class and attempted to access an element, it would look something like this:

```
my_array = MultiArray<4>();
element = my_array(2,5,4,1);
```

How might I go about doing this using templates? Is this even possible?

Comment: i suggest using `boost::multi_array_ref`

Comment: I recently answered a closely related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664127/create-a-multidimensional-array-dynamically-in-c/47664858#47664858), about a dynamic, multi-dimensional array which allows reshaping and provides element access.

Comment: @bnaecker That is an attractive option, I like the ease of reshaping, and referencing a vector with indices (which I can just change outside) deals with the speed issues! Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
template<class T>
struct slice {
    T* data = 0;
    std::size_t const* stride = 0;
    slice operator[](std::size_t I)const {
        return{ data + I* *stride, stride + 1 };
    }
    operator T&()const {
      return *data;
    }
    T& operator=(typename std::remove_const<T>::type in)const {
      *data = std::move(in); return *data;
    }
};
```

store a `vector<T>` of data, and an `std::vector<std::size_t> stride` of strides, where `stride[0]` is the element-stride that the first index wants.

```
template<class T>
struct buffer {
  std::vector<T> data;
  std::vector<std::size_t> strides;

  buffer( std::vector<std::size_t> sizes, std::vector<T> d ):
    data(std::move(d)),
    strides(sizes)
  {
    std::size_t scale = 1;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i<sizes.size(); ++i){
      auto next = scale*strides[sizes.size()-1-i];
      strides[sizes.size()-1-i] = scale;
      scale=next;
    }
  }
  slice<T> get(){ return {data.data(), strides.data()}; }
  slice<T const> get()const{ return {data.data(), strides.data()}; }
};
```

[c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14).  [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95e3faff7c6e9df9).

If you use not enough `[]`s it refers to the first element of the subarray in question.  If you use too many it does UB.  It does zero dimension checking, both in count of dimensions and in size.

Both can be added, but would cost performance.

The number of dimensions is dynamic.  You can split `buffer` into two types, one that owns the buffer and the other that provides the dimensioned view of it.

Comment: I tried to edit this for you, but the change was rejected in peer review. here were the comments:

added additional unit value to strides array. corrected strides array offset on buffer get() accessor. highest stride shouldnt be part of index computation. otherwise, subsequent increments hop by an amount equal to the last stride entry. also changed a capitaliztion typo 'I'->'i' in for loop

Comment: here is the change:

template<class T>
struct buffer {
  std::vector<T> data;
  std::vector<std::size_t> strides;

  buffer( std::vector<std::size_t> sizes, std::vector<T> d ):data(std::move(d)), strides(sizes){
    std::size_t scale = 1;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i<sizes.size(); ++i){
      strides[sizes.size()-1-i]*=scale;
      scale=strides[sizes.size()-1-i];
    }
    strides.emplace_back(1);
    data.resize(scale);
  }
  slice<T> get(){ return { data.data(), strides.data() + 1 }; }
  slice<T> operator[](std::size_t I) { return get()[I]; }
};

Comment: @chrisg You had an error in your design; but mine had an error to.  Fixed both.  The `emplace_back` patched over my error, it didn't fix it.

Comment: @user5915738 re your edit: `slice<T>` follows pointer rules for const.  What you want a `slice<T> const` ro be is really a `slice<T const>`.  `[]` and `*` on pointers is const, even if the pointed-to object is not const.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you could use [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html), [`boost::multi_array_ref`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#multi_array_ref) to be more specific. `boost::multi_array_ref` does exactly what you want: it wraps continuous data array into an object that may be treated as a multidimensional array. You may also use `boost::multi_array_ref::array_view` for slicing purposes.

I cannot provide you with any benchmark results, but from my experience, I can say that `boost::multi_array_ref` works pretty fast.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use C++17, so variadic template folding, and [row major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), I suppose you can write something like (caution: not tested)

```
template <template ... Args>
float & operator() (Args ... dims)
 {
   static_assert( sizeof...(Args) == TDim , "wrong number of indexes" );
   // or SFINAE enable instead of static_assert()

   std::size_t pos { 0U };
   std::size_t i   { 0U };

   ( pos *= MaxDimX[i++], pos += dims, ... );

   return internal_array[pos];
 }
```

OTPS (Off Topic Post Scriptum): your `MaxDimX`, if I understand correctly, is a vector of dimensions; so should be an **unsigned** integer, non a signed `int`; usually, for indexes, is used `std::size_t` [see Note 1].

OTPS 2: if you know compile time the number of dimensions (`TDim`, right?) instead of a `std::vector`, I suggest the use of a `std::array`; I mean

```
std::array<std::size_t, TDim>  MaxDimX;
```

**-- EDIT --**

If you can't use C++17, you can use the trick of the unused array initialization to obtain something similar.

I mean

```
template <template ... Args>
float & operator() (Args ... dims)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   static_assert( sizeof...(Args) == TDim , "wrong number of indexes" );
   // or SFINAE enable instead of static_assert()

   std::size_t pos { 0U };
   std::size_t i   { 0U };

   (void)unused { (pos *= MaxDimX[i++], pos += dims, 0) ... };

   return internal_array[pos];
 }
```

Note 1: as pointed by Julius, the use of a signed or an unsigned integer for indexes is controversial.

So I try to explain better why I suggest to use an unsigned value (`std::size_t`, by example) for they.

The point is that (as far I know) all Standard Template Library is designed to use unsigned integer for index values. You can see it by the value returned by the `size()` method and by the fact that access methods that receive an index, as `at()` or `operator[]`, receive an unsigned value.

Right or wrong, the language itself is designed to return a `std::size_t` from the old `sizeof()` and from more recent variadic `sizeof...()`. The same class `std::index_sequence` is an alias for `std::integer_sequence` with a fixed unsigned, again `std::size_t`, type.

In a world designed to use unsigned integers for indexes, the use of a signed integer for they it's possible but, IMHO, dangerous (because error prone).

Comment: Concerning `signed` vs `unsigned`: The issue is not as clear as you indicate: computing differences with `unsigned`s can yield surprising results and moreover the compiler can more heavily optimize `signed` computations because of the undefined overflow.

Comment: @Julius - I confess that I had not even thought about the performances. And I wouldn't give to much importance to it because (I suppose) heavily depend from specific hardware and from compiler optimizations. My suggestion comes from the observation that all STL treat sizes (`size()` methods) and index based methods (`operator[]` and `at()`) as based over unsigned types, usually `std::size_t`. Mixing signed and unsigned types can be dangerous, very very dangerous ("I've seen things you people wouldn't believe...").

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I understand that there are these different positions in the `signed` vs. `unsigned` discussion and I surely accept your opinion. My intention was just to point out that **different opinions exist** concerning this question. Hence I think this OTPS worsens your answer: [quote start] your `MaxDimX`, if I understand correctly, is a vector of dimensions; so should be an **unsigned** integer, non a signed `int` [quote end]. It it just not as clear as you present it here: in my opinion, `int` could be the perfect choice (depending on the exact requirements of course).

Comment: @Julius - I know that exist different opinions and I respect they; but, in my experience, the use of signed integers is really error prone; anyway, you convinced me that my suggestion deserve a better explanation in the answer, non in a comment. Answer modified.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this pattern several times when creating a class templates of a matrix class with variable dimensions.

**Matrix.h**

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H

template<typename Type, size_t... Dims>
class Matrix {
public:
    static const size_t numDims_ = sizeof...(Dims);

private:
    size_t numElements_;

    std::vector<Type> elements_;
    std::vector<size_t> strides_; // Technically this vector contains the size of each dimension... (its shape)
    // actual strides would be the width in memory of each element to that dimension of the container.
    // A better name for this container would be dimensionSizes_ or shape_ 

public:
    Matrix() noexcept;

    template<typename... Arg>
    Matrix( Arg&&... as  ) noexcept;

    const Type& operator[]( size_t idx ) const;

    size_t numElements() const {
        return elements_.size();
    }

    const std::vector<size_t>& strides() const {
        return strides_;
    }

    const std::vector<Type>& elements() const {
        return elements_;
    }

}; // matrix

#include "Matrix.inl"

#endif // MATRIX_H
```

**Matrix.inl**

```
template<typename Type, size_t... Dims>
Matrix<Type, Dims...>::Matrix() noexcept :
strides_( { Dims... } ) {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    auto mult = std::accumulate( begin( strides_ ), end( strides_ ), 1, std::multiplies<>() );
    numElements_ = mult;
    elements_.resize( numElements_ );
} // Matrix


template<typename Type, size_t... Dims>
template<typename... Arg>
Matrix<Type, Dims...>::Matrix( Arg&&... as ) noexcept   : 
elements_( { as... } ),
strides_( { Dims... } ){
    numElements_ = elements_.size();
} // Matrix

template<typename T, size_t... d>
const T& Matrix<T,d...>::operator[]( size_t idx ) const {
    return elements_[idx];
} // Operator[]
```

**Matrix.cpp**

```
#include "Matrix.h"
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "matrix.h"

int main() {

    Matrix<int, 3, 3> mat3x3( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 );

    for ( size_t idx = 0; idx < mat3x3.numElements(); idx++ ) {
        std::cout << mat3x3.elements()[idx] << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n\nnow using array index operator\n\n";

    for ( size_t idx = 0; idx < mat3x3.numElements(); idx++ ) {
        std::cout << mat3x3[idx] << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n\ncheck the strides\n\n";
    for ( size_t idx = 0; idx < mat3x3.numDims_; idx++ ) {
        std::cout << mat3x3.strides()[idx] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "=================================\n\n";

    Matrix<float, 5, 2, 9, 7> mf5x2x9x7;
    // Check Strides
    // Num Elements
    // Total Size
    std::cout << "The total number of dimensions are: " << mf5x2x9x7.numDims_ << "\n";
    std::cout << "The total number of elements are: " << mf5x2x9x7.numElements() << "\n";
    std::cout << "These are the strides: \n";
    for ( size_t n = 0; n < mf5x2x9x7.numDims_; n++ ) {
        std::cout << mf5x2x9x7.strides()[n] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "The elements are: ";
    for ( size_t n = 0; n < mf5x2x9x7.numElements(); n++ ) {
        std::cout << mf5x2x9x7[n] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";      

    std::cout << "\nPress any key and enter to quit." << std::endl;
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;

    return 0;

} // main
```

This is a simple variable multidimensional matrix class of the `Same Type <T>`

You can create a matrix of floats, ints, chars etc of varying sizes such as a `2x2`, `2x3`, `5x3x7`, `4x9x8x12x2x19`. This is a very simple but versatile class.

It is using `std::vector<>` so the search time is linear. The larger the multi - dimensional matrix grows in dimensions the larger the internal container will grow depending on the size of each dimension; this can "explode" fairly quick if each individual dimensions are of a large dimensional size for example: a `9x9x9` is only a `3 dimensional volumetric matrix` that has many more elements than a `2x2x2x2x2` which is a `5 dimensional volumetric matrix`. The first matrix has `729` elements where the second matrix has only `32` elements.

I did not include a <strike>default constructor</strike>, copy constructor, move constructor, nor any overloaded constructors that would accept either a `std::container<T>` or another `Matrix<T,...>`. This can be done as an exercise for the OP.

<strike>I also did not include any simple functions that would give the size of total elements from the main container, nor the number of total dimensions which would be the size of the `strides` container size. The OP should be able to implement these very simply.</strike>

As for the `strides` and for indexing with multiple dimensional coordinates the OP would need to use the `stride` values to compute the appropriate indexes again I leave this as the main exercise.

**EDIT** - I went ahead and added a default constructor, moved some members to private section of the class, and added a few access functions. I did this because I just wanted to demonstrate in the main function the power of this class even when creating an empty container of its type.

Even more you can take user Yakk's answer with his "stride & slice" algorithm and should easily be able to plug it right into this class giving you the full functionality of what you are looking for.